# find the difference between two datetimes in seconds

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have had a quick look around and I can't find an answer to this in vb.net or something that I can convert into vb.net.

I have two DateTimes in vb.net's 'Date' class. I would like to find the difference between these in seconds. I can do a-b, but the answer will still be a 'date'. I can use `.seconds` `.minutes` etc. and multiply but I will hit problems when I come to months.

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to write some elaborate-ish code?

Many Thanks

Comment: "I can do a-b, but the answer will still be a 'date'" - is not correct. It will be a `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx) the `DateTime` values from each other - the returned type will be a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Get the `TotalSeconds` value from it.

```
(date1 - date2).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 8):

There actually is also a function made for this `DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, d1, d2)`

Comment: Works like a charm.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why I am getting result as 63616023225.5405

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
Dim secs As Double = DateTime.Today.Subtract(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)).TotalSeconds
```

Look at [DateTime.Subtract Method (DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) and [TimeSpan.TotalSeconds Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx)